# Unable to get string of query using driverspy

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j, prepared-statement, jtds

I am working on a project where I need to log query in Log files and add those queries to my assert statement as well

I have build prepared statements using below driver

```
net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy
```

And url

```
jdbc:log4jdbc:sybase:Tds ........
```

Dependencies I am using is as below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

PrepareStatement Example:

```
public void getTest(MyBean bean) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = DatabaseUtil.getDatabaseConnection();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(objTestQueryUtil.getQuery("GET_Test"));
            ps.setString(1, bean.getTypeOfTest());
            ps.setString(2, bean.getTest());
            ps.setString(3, bean.getTestState());
            ps.setString(4, bean.getTestStep());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                bean.setTest(rs.getInt("Test"));
            }
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            AutomationLog.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }finally {
            DatabaseUtil.close(conn,ps,rs);
        }
    }
```

In my assert class, the sql should see in my assert code like:

```
Assert.assertTrue("Got Test "+query, true);
```

Can you please tell me if there any way around by which I can get query in variables in java also, currently query directly logs into the log file and I am not able to find anyway by which I can get them in my script, i.e store on any variable etc

Another dependencies or solution are also welcome if current dependencies do not have such provisions for pre-prepared-statements

Answer (score 2):

This is not the optimal solution but it can solve your problem:

Open your jtds jar file (or download the jtds source files and import them in your IDE), find and decompile the class net.sf.log4jdbc.StatementSpy.class,

- add a static String variable in that class, let's call it myLastExecutedSQL
- edit the reportSQL() method, assign the sql method parameter to your static variable
- compile the new class (or regenerate the jar) and use it in your project
- in your test class you will be able to access the last executed query with StatementSpy.myLastExecutedSQL

As you're using maven you will have to replace the jar on the maven home folder

The drawback of this is that you cannot use it in a multi-threaded environment, but it will do the trick.

I hope it's clear enough

Comment: Thanks you very much Deadspock ... I will try this tomorrow for sure .. ye i m using maven .. does I can override that class or it is an seal class ... if i can override it somehow then I guess it will do the trick

Comment: You can override it on the jar, usually I download the source code, do the adjustment, compilation and then, I just replace the class file on the jar and that's it.

Comment: Is that mean there is no provision where I can override an function of an lib in my source code without touching the jar itself ...

Comment: In this case I think you cannot override it, that particular method is protected, and in case you'll be able, the method on the parent class will be the one to be called by the other internal classes, it's a generic method for writing queries on log, it's needed to modify the jar, sorry

Comment: Thanks DeadSpock for your input ... voting up you for now